# Ambiguous overload with functor base classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, template-specialization

I was trying to write the same code as the `overload` struct here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit and extend it to work with functions as well.

Here is the code https://wandbox.org/permlink/5Z2jsEjOewkGoPeX reproduced below

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

namespace {
    template <typename Func>
    class OverloadFuncImpl : public Func {
    public:
        template <typename F>
        explicit OverloadFuncImpl(F&& f) : Func{std::forward<F>(f)} {}
        using Func::operator();
    };
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    class OverloadFuncImpl<ReturnType (*) (Args...)> {
    public:
        template <typename F>
        explicit OverloadFuncImpl(F&& f) : func{std::forward<F>(f)} {}
        ReturnType operator()(Args... args) {
            return this->func(args...);
        }
    private:
        ReturnType (*func) (Args...);
    };

    template <typename... Funcs>
    class Overload;
    template <typename Func, typename... Funcs>
    class Overload<Func, Funcs...>
            : public OverloadFuncImpl<Func>,
              public Overload<Funcs...> {
    public:
        template <typename F, typename... Fs>
        explicit Overload(F&& f, Fs&&... fs)
            : OverloadFuncImpl<Func>{std::forward<F>(f)},
            Overload<Funcs...>{std::forward<Fs>(fs)...} {}
        using OverloadFuncImpl<Func>::operator();
        using Overload<Funcs...>::operator();
    };
    template <typename Func>
    class Overload<Func> : public OverloadFuncImpl<Func> {
    public:
        template <typename F>
        explicit Overload(F&& f) : OverloadFuncImpl<Func>{std::forward<F>(f)} {}
        using OverloadFuncImpl<Func>::operator();
    };
}

template <typename... Funcs>
auto make_overload(Funcs&&... funcs) {
    return Overload<std::decay_t<Funcs>...>{std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)...};
}

char foo(char ch) {
    return ch;
}

int main() {
    auto overloaded = make_overload(
        [&](int integer) { return integer; },
        [&](std::string str) { return str; },
        [&](double d) { return d; },
        foo);

    assert(overloaded("something") == "something");
    assert(overloaded(1.1) == 1.1);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get

```
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/cassert:44:0,
                 from prog.cc:3:
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:66:26: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
     assert(overloaded(1.1) == 1.1);
                          ^
prog.cc:62:21: note: candidate 1: main()::<lambda(double)>
         [&](double d) { return d; },
                     ^
prog.cc:19:20: note: candidate 2: ReturnType {anonymous}::OverloadFuncImpl<ReturnType (*)(Args ...)>::operator()(Args ...) [with ReturnType = char; Args = {char}]
         ReturnType operator()(Args... args) {
                    ^~~~~~~~
```

There are several problems with the compiler and standard interpretations that make it necessary to import the `operator()` one by one.  But somehow the `operator()` of the function specialization of `OverloadFuncImpl` does not seem to get imported via `using` properly.

Note that the code above works just fine when I don't use `OverloadFuncImpl` or exclude the function partial specialization of `OverloadFuncImpl`.

I already got this code working with a workaround, but I am just wondering why the code above doesn't work.  I can't seem to figure it out...  Why is it that when I have imported all the `operator()` of all the base classes.  There is still am ambiguous overload problem?

I tried to reproduce the error in a smaller context but was unable to...

Comment: Btw, this is not directly relevant to your question but: your function pointer implementation has further problems. Just try creating an overload from a function pointer that takes an rvalue reference.

Comment: @NirFriedman Which part are you talking about?  The constructor or the call operator?

Comment: The call operator. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d3469ea05c357c1

Comment: @NirFriedman yeah I accidentally attached an older version of that code..  I added a `std::forward` to the `operator()` later

Comment: Unfortunately, if you add a `std::forward` without templating the call operator, you still have issues; you are copying object twice for example if passed by value. And if you template and do perfect forwarding, it will break other things. Seems like a real pain to do exactly correctly.

Comment: @NirFriedman yeah, it's the best way to do this that I see currently..  Not sure what workarounds there are to this if any

Comment: @NirFriedman Actually an `enable_if` might solve the issue by constraining the template to only work with the types passed in.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to suggest. Templating with an enable_if, you can just do a decltype on the same call you use in the body which is relatively simple, and I think solves all of the non-crazy cases well.

Comment: @NirFriedman Also a neat `decltype(auto)` on the return type in that case

Comment: @Curious: That code should answer the newer deleted question that you posted ([how-to-mimic-overloading-with-a-set-of-function-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965306/how-to-mimic-overloading-with-a-set-of-function-pointers)).

Comment: @Jarod42 its not that simple. Simply constraining the types based on whether the arguments are the same or not wouldnt work perfectly. Neither would just enabling if the arguments can work with the function

Comment: If you un-delete question and show problematic case, I can see how overcome your problem (if possible).

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I came up with a solution myself, which is why I deleted it, in the past when I have answered my questions it wasn't well received.  So I just deleted it

Comment: @Jarod42 do you suggest I undelete it and post the answer I had in mind?

Comment: As the question might help future users and question is interesting IMO, you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    ReturnType operator()(Args... args) const {
//                                      ^^^^^
        return this->func(args...);
    }
```

---

Effectively the relevant candidates in the overload set at issue are

```
 char operator()(char);
 double operator()(double) const;
```

called on a non-`const` object with an argument of type `double`.

The first wins on the implicit object parameter; the second wins on the actual function parameter. Ambiguity ensues.

Comment: Any idea why the error message did not mention this?

Comment: @Curious I guess the point that is easy to miss, is that a lambda's operator() is implicitly const. That's why lambdas must be declared mutable when necessary. That makes TCs solution not immediately jump out (at least, not to me when I read the error message).

Comment: @NirFriedman yeah I got that,  I just would never have thought about that myself :(

Comment: @T.C. this is a great catch, I will award a 100 or 50 point bounty to this after 2 days when this becomes eligible for a bounty :)